# How can I save a really large PNG from chrome://tracing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I created custom JSON in "chrome://tracing" format so I can visualize it. In this case it's disk space usage. How can I save a large PNG from chrome://tracing? Much larger than the screen. A regular size PNG does not show enough detail.

[image]

Comment: Inspecting the page in devtools I see it's a `<canvas>` element which means the page draws only the viewport portion. You'll have to write your own visualizer/converter based on the source code of [Catapult](https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult). There might be existing solutions for this.

Comment: Thanks. I realize a command-line way to generate the image is also a requirement. So a build/test process could spit out the image. I might try to make a treemap instead of using chrome tracing, maybe a better depiction. But will checkout Catapult mailing list. Thanks again.